# Google Stackdriver: Group by distinct values

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver

Lets say I have a number of requests in my stackdriver log. Each request is associated with a certain user. Naturally there are several requests for the same user at any time.

I now want to create a metric/chart in Google stackdriver which shows my the number of distinct users at any timeslot.

Example:
10:00:00 - user X
10:02:00 - user Y
10:10:00 - user X
10:12:00 - user X
10:12:00 - user Y
10:15:00 - user Z

The desired outcome is that for the timeslot 10:00 (10:00 - 10:59) a overall number of 3 users is shown. (user x, y and z have been active in this time range).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your best course of action with this will be to export the logs into something like big query and run a distinct count query on the timeframes you want to view seeing as stackdriver only has a `count` function and no `count distinct`